# Mostrar SplashScreen mientras se carga la aplicación en Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo implementado una splashcreen mediante una `activity` que se infla de su `layout` con una imagen centrada, pero lo que me encuentro que si es la primera vez que se instala la app, durante la carga/compilación se muestra una pantalla en blanco, más o menos 6 segundos, la segunda vez que inicias la app inicia directamente con la SplashScreen.

Graficamente así

**La Primera vez** que se ejecuta la app despues de instalación o borrar datos del menú configuración

(click abrir app).........................(splashscreen)------(listo)

**La segunda vez** que se abre la app

(click abrir app)(splashscreen)------(listo)

Mi pregunta si hay alguna forma de poner una splashcreen durante ese periodo de pre-carga de Android.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Estilo `AppTheme.SplashTheme` del Tema que hereda la activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
</style>
```

Layout XML splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorSplashScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/about.alt_logo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

SplashActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/*
config_longAnimTime   = 400
config_mediumAnimTime = 300
config_shortAnimTime  = 150
*/
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = "SplashActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1200;
        final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_OFFSET = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called with: " + "savedInstanceState = [" + savedInstanceState + "]");
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                final LinearLayout img = (LinearLayout) SplashActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);

                Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                fadeOut.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime));

                fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
                {
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Create an intent that will start the main activity.
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                                //Apply splash exit (fade out) and main entry (fade in) animation transitions.
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, android.R.anim.fade_out);

                                //Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it.
                                SplashActivity.this.finish();

                            }
                        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_OFFSET);

                    }
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                });

                img.startAnimation(fadeOut);

                Log.d(TAG, "finish SplashScreen: " + SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

    }

}
```

**Actualización:**
Se muestra la pantalla blanca porque hereda del tema light, porque si añado el estilo del tema, se muestra negra la pantalla.

```
    <item name="android:background">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#FF000000</item>
```

Creo que la solución recae en implementar dibujar el icono mediante la carga del tema antes de usar un layout xml,  abrir app ---> se aplica tema ----> carga layout en la interfaz.

Comment: lo que comentas puede ser por ART que usa (AOT) por lo que no deberia de notarse tanto como si usaras Dalvik (aunque igual esta usando Dalvik) pues este usa (JIT). ART compila a lenguaje intermedio, todo el codigo de la aplicación va a ser precompilado durante la instalacion una vez. Pero lo que tu comentas sucede durante la ejecucion contando de que no fuerea cosa tuya creo que podrian ser por dos cosa 1 que este usando JIT pues este hace ajustes durante la ejecucion o

Comment: 2 que ART tambien este haciendo algunos ajustes aunque en principio usa AOT, pero igual hace alguna cosa en tiempo de ejecucion, quizas por eso notas que una vez es mas rapido que la siguiente pero solo es una idea, y no soy un experto en esos temas, espero ayude. Saludos

Comment: jaja o sin tanto lio igual es la cache de android que igual tu abres la aplicacion y despues de cerrarla la vuelves abrir y vamas rapido, podrias por curiosidad abrir la aplicacion por primera vez cerrarla, apagar el dispositivo, encenderlo y lanzar la aplicacion a a ver si tarda lo mismo que la primera vez. Saludos

Comment: Si es lo que me temía al principio cosa de ART pero, como bien dices en la instalación se compila la app y no en la ejecución, eso hasta que no tengamos Android N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
Leyendo ese post [Un splashscreen eficiente (en)](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd)
Añado lo opaque

Definir el fondo del splashscreen en un drawable `background_splash.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorSplashScreen"/>
    <item android:top="-48dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Aplico un desplazamiento superior para ajustar bien la transición de la pantalla pre-carga hacia el splashscreen

Asignar como fondo el drawable creado en styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

De paso elimino la idea de tener texto que aparece debajo del icono de la app, porque no encontrado como hacerlo directamente como un drawable.

layout splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorSplashScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/about.alt_logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Código opcional** para cambiar el tema al vuelo, en caso de no hacer un splascreen con un activity intermedio:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp); //Tu Tema general
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Para asignar splashscreen en diferentes tamaños de pantalla y densidad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574363/android-splash-screen-image-sizes-to-fit-all-devices

Answer (score 6):

Cuando deseas que al iniciar la pantalla de inicio de la aplicación  (SplashScreen) **no muestre ese molesto fondo blanco**, se pude solucionar fácilmente creando un tema el cual relacionarias a la actividad:

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/fondo_splash</item>
   </style>
```

En realidad la propiedad que define el fondo al iniciar la actividad es `android:windowBackground` y puedes agregar una imagen (`@drawable/` )

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/fondo_splash</item>
```

o un color (`@color/`):

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/fondo_splash</item>
```

Dentro de nuestro `AndroidManifest.xml` podemos definir el tema en el nivel de la aplicación :

```
  <application
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

o de alguna actividad especifica:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
   android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
```

con esto siempre aseguramos cargar un fondo (drawable o color), antes de cargar una imagen o iniciar completamente la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al usar un drawable, dentro de este puede contener lo que una imagen o texto no es asi ?

Comment: Exacto, puede ser una imagen, un gradiente, un color, etc.

Comment: entiendo gracias !